# C# convert byte[] containing a c-style string to string - NOT Encoding.GetString(byte[])

Tags: c#, string

stupid me tries to convert a byte-array received from an external source not unter my control to a string. (And yes, I do know about `Encoding.GetString(byte[])`.

What I have so far:

```
void myfunc()
{
    byte[] rawData = new byte[ 128 ];

    for( int i = 0; i < rawData.Length; ++i )
    {
        rawData[ i ] = 0;
    }

    rawData[ 0 ] = (byte)'H';
    rawData[ 1 ] = (byte)'e';
    rawData[ 2 ] = (byte)'l';
    rawData[ 3 ] = (byte)'l';
    rawData[ 4 ] = (byte)'o';


    string asString = Encoding.UTF8.GetString( rawData, 0, rawData.Length );

    string asRealString = Encoding.UTF8.GetString( rawData );
}
```

Both strings do contain the Hello part but also a lot of \0's afterwards - which is not the thing I expected. 
The output from the debugger:
asRealString =

```
"Hello\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0"
```

Is there any way that would geive me a string like "Hello" ?

I did goolge,but all I got was `Encoding.GetString(byte[])` ...

**EDIT**: The creatin of the byte array is outside my scope! I do get it as part of a larger, C-Style struct. And there is no leading length of the string. 
Also I was hoping there iss ome built in way to tdo it and I did not have to find the first \o and tehn convert knowing the length....

**EDIT**
Here is what I used in the end:

```
private static string convertCString( byte[] buffer, int maxLength, Encoding targetEncoding )
{
    int length = 0;
    int realMax = buffer.Length < maxLength ? buffer.Length : maxLength;

    for( 
         ; 0 != buffer[length] && length < realMax
         ; ++length )
    {}

    return targetEncoding.GetString( buffer, 0, length );
}
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Just find the first `0`:

```
    int len = Array.IndexOf(rawData, (byte)0); // maybe some bounds check too
    string asString = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(rawData, 0, len);
```

Comment: Thanks Narc, though not really the way I liked it (I was hoping for some built in stuff). I implented it now with a for-loop so I can do some boundary check as you already pointed out!

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
Encoding.UTF8.GetString( rawData ).Trim();
```

Answer (score 2):

> The creatin of the byte array is outside my scope! I do get it as part of a larger, C-Style struct. And there is no leading length of the string.

It *may* be possible to do this in a built-in way by having the marshaller do it for you.

I'm assuming that what you have now is like:

```
struct CStruct
{
  [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst=128)]
  public byte[] data;
}
```

Try changing it to:

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, CharSet=CharSet.Ansi)]
struct CStruct
{
  [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst=128)]
  public string data;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Why didn't you expect that? You explicitly told it to do that to start with:

```
byte[] rawData = new byte[ 128 ];

for( int i = 0; i < rawData.Length; ++i )
{
    rawData[ i ] = 0;   // RIGHT HERE
}
```

The above code creates a 128 item byte array and the for loop populates it. Then your code explicitly changes the value of the first 5 bytes. If you don't want to see the \0, then you need either not to put it there or exclude it from the array before sending it to `GetString`.

Comment: CLR will initialize each array element with (byte)0

Comment: @Viach... : I get that, but his code does explicitly initialize each element. Not being aware of his limitations, the "not to put it there" was a not very direct way of saying "initialize/allocate only the pieces you need". Reading some of his comments, that doesn't sound like it will be an option for him.

Answer (score 0):

When you do

```
string asString = Encoding.UTF8.GetString( rawData, 0, rawData.Length );
```

Instead of passing in `rawData.Length`, can you not just pass in the actual length of the string?

Comment: thanks, for the input, but unfortunaltely not. It is part of a larger struct originating in a C program that delivers that struct via socket to me...

Answer (score 0):

```
new string(Array.ConvertAll(rawData, x => (char)x))
```

The string constructor will terminate the string at the first \0.

Answer (score 0):

```
void myfunc()
{
    byte[] rawData = new byte[ 128 ];

    //CLR will initialize each elemnet in arry to the 0
    //for( int i = 0; i < rawData.Length; ++i )
    //{
    //    rawData[ i ] = 0;
    //}

    rawData[ 0 ] = (byte)'H';
    rawData[ 1 ] = (byte)'e';
    rawData[ 2 ] = (byte)'l';
    rawData[ 3 ] = (byte)'l';
    rawData[ 4 ] = (byte)'o';

    // you should know length of the received string (each IO read method return number of read bytes), if you don't know it you can try to search 0 as the EOS
    var receivedBytes = Array.IndexOf(rawData, 0);
    string asString = Encoding.ASCII.GetString( rawData, 0, receivedBytes );
}
```

Comment: yes, every I/O method does this. But as I added in my comment it is part of a larger struct, so the read returns the length of the overall structure.

Comment: Anyway you should have a posibility to get field data length, isn't it?

Comment: I do know the max length, but not the length of the string that is currently contained therein.